# Query to get the user list which are belongs to a group

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I can select the users which has 'sex = 2' by this sql

```
createQueryBuilder('s')
->where('s.sex = 2');
```

How can I select the users which are belonging to group A?

My tables are below.

my user table.

```
ID | name |sex
1  | bob  |1
2  | kayo |2
3  | ken  |1
```

my fos_group table

```
ID | name
1  | student
2  | teacher
```

my fos_user_user_group

```
user_id | group_id
1       | 1
2       | 2
3       | 1
```

it means that

Bob and Ken are belonging to group_1(student)

Kayo is belonging to group_2(teacher)

I would like to select the lists from user table which are belonging to 'student' or 'teacher'

---

What I want to have is username list belonging to student.

ID | name    | sex
1  | bob     |1
3  | ken     |1

Comment: what is your desired output. Please put in a tabular form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a join first, and then filter on the association property.

```
$entityRepository
  ->createQueryBuilder('s')
  ->join('s.groups', 'g') // Assuming the association on your user entity is 'groups'
  ->where('g.name = :group')->setParameter('group', 'student');
```

See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins for examples of filtering on associations with DQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    g.name AS GroupName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.name) AS Users
FROM fos_group AS g
INNER JOIN fos_user_user_group AS ug ON ug.group_id = g.ID
INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.id = ug.user_id
GROUP BY g.name
```

OUTPUT :

```
GroupName   |   Users
---------------------------
student     |   bob ,   ken
teacher     |   kayo
```

Comment: thanks raheel shan.I use the Ryan answer,but I should write the desired table data in advance